Getting error while updating in raspberry pi
Code :sudo apt update
Error:
Ign:1 https://packages.sury.org/php bullseye InRelease
Err:2 https://packages.sury.org/php bullseye Release
Cannot initiate the connection to packages.sury.org:443 (103.180.115.10). connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Hit:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye InRelease Hit:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://packages.sury.org/php bullseye Release' no longer has a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
I tried To update in raspberry pi terminal
But it ended up in error showing like this
